# Excel Dropdown list that shows certain fields

Tags: excel, dropdown, vba

I am trying to create a dropdown list which, when a number is clicked on, will show that many fields. The following picture may help:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

I know how to create a dropdown list but in the field H5, if the number 8 is picked for example, I want 8 company fields to appear in H11-V11.
Likewise, if the dropdown list in H6 the number 4 is picked for the amount of criteria, I want 4 'Description of Criteria' fields in G13-G17 etc.

Comment: you could simple use the formula like IF($H$6>=1,"Description 1", "") and add update this formula for subsequent descriptions.

Comment: You can use the Worksheet_Change event to monitor for changes in H5 and H6 and then take the appropriate action (ie. recreate the table with the new number of rows/columns)

Comment: Thanks Anand! That works for the criteria, I suppose I can use it for the companies as well. However, say I pick 3 companies, how would I hide the information and formulas already in the cells for the companies 4,5,6 etc? (O11 to V19 in the picture I posted)

Comment: for example when you pick 3 for criteria, formula in cell "G16" would be IF($H$6>=4,"Description", "") which will result in blank value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment section, you could simply use the formula for this.
For example for criteria you will use formula IF($H$6>=1,"Description 1", "") in cell "G13", IF($H$6>=2,"Description 2", "") in cell "G14", IF($H$6>=3,"Description 3", "") in cell "G15", IF($H$6>=4,"Description 4", "") in cell "G16" and so on.

So when you pick "3" for criteria, formula in cell "G16" will show blank while formula in cell "G13", "G14" and "G15" will show you description value.

You can use similar analogy for companies as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anand! I think I know how to go about it now, really appreciate this!